# Read range value from a STRING cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have many formulas (20+) using data from some range in a single spreadsheet.

The problem is that when I copy those formulas to some other part of the spreadsheet to handle another range, I have to manually modify each of them to adapt them with the new range value !!

What I'm looking for is -for example- to enter the range value in one cell as a string, so all my formulas will automatically use that string value as a range.

In other words, let's say that my formula in cell `A2` is calculating the sum of a range using `=SUM(C32:C45)`

If cell `A1` contains the value `C32:C45` I want to modify my `A2` formula to use that range.

I tried `=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(row(),column()-1)))` but it didnt work... What Am I missing ?

Any other ideas that helps avoiding the multiple editing of each formulas are welcome (hopefully using native google-spreadsheet functions only -no scripting unless it's the only way :< -)

Comment: Oh, good catch... I needed a double `indirect` function... I didnt know about named ranges either, that for sure would be helpfull too... Thanks a lot and feel free to post a proper answer so I'll accpet it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in ColumnA `column()-1` won't suit. In keeping with the OP's approach it seems:

```
=sum(indirect(indirect(address(row()-1,column()))))
```

would suit though perhaps also the simpler:

```
=sum(NamedRange1)
```

where `NamedRage1` is C32:C45.

Comment: One more question (I dont think it worth being posted as new): what if I want to get the adjacent range from a given one. ie: I have `C32:C45` and I want to get `D32:D45` or `E32:E45`(different column, same rows), is there a simple fast way to do that ? (instead of string replace and so on...)

Comment: lol, it's fine... I'll try to do what I want differently, If I couldnt, i'll post a new question